# Action bar looks cut while using Theme.AppCompat.Dialog

Tags: android, dialog, android-actionbar, styles, themes

I wished to make one of my activities to look like a dialog and used a Theme.AppCompat.Dialog theme for it, but it made it's action bar to look bad (see below).

Now background is cut to the length of the title string and I cant't find any theme property to fix it.(

[image]

What can be done to avoid it?

Related part of styles.xml:

```
<style name="DeviceListTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog">
    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
</style>
```

I start the activity using the following code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, DeviceListActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE);
```

Comment: Paste the code in style.xml and the code in activity relevant to showing the actionbar

Comment: Is `Select device` the title? or a regular TextView?

Comment: @JuanjoVega - "Select device" is the title set in the manifest.xml. I've not tried to assign a custom actionbar layout in any way.

Comment: If you found my answer useful, could you accept it? ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, when I encountered this problem, I tried using `supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);` but this didn't work for me and had no effect.

The alternative method to remove the bar at the top of your dialog activity would be to create a custom style and apply it to that activity.

In `styles.xml`, create a new style like so:

```
<style name="MyCustomDialog" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
</style>
```

Now, in `AndroidManifest.xml`, add in `android:theme="@style/MyCustomDialog"` to your activity.

Of course, `MyCustomDialog` can be renamed to anything you want.

Answer (score 0):

Use DialogWhenLarge instead of standard Dialog style:

```
<style name="MyDialogTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DialogWhenLarge">
...
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the same problem this way:

Activity:

```
public class MyActivity extends android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.my_layout);
        setTitle("View task");
    }
}
```

Theme:

```
<style name="Theme.MyDialog" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">false</item>
</style>
```

Manifest:

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity" android:theme="@style/Theme.MyDialog"/>
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: I don't get anything on the screen! Do i have to set a fixed size?

Comment: No, you shouldn't set a fixed size.

Comment: How do I make it full width then? Or a percentage ... Or add padding or something?

Comment: You should examine '@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog' and its parents. There are a lot of parents and dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

**Its Working**

```
<style name="AppThemeDialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
       <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
       <item name="android:spinnerStyle">@style/holoSpinner</item>
</style>

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);
       setTitle("Batches");
   }
```